# Exclude getters & setters from sonar method count

Tags: php, sonarqube

There's a rule in SonarQube, similar to the PHPMD one, "Classes should not have too many methods". Is there a way to exclude the getters / setters from this count? Because PHPMD excludes all methods prefixed with "get" or "set". If you have 10 properties in a class, you already reached the 20 methods / class limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter for doing this yet, see [Classes should not have too many methods](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=php%3AS1448).

But you can request it as improvement or create your own pull request on [GitHub](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-php).

Comment: now @ 2019 isn't there a new feature with that setup/configuration ?